# Is there any way convert text to time in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, time

Is there any way convert text to time type?
Code in postgresql as below:

```
to_char(localtimestamp(0),'HH24:mi:SS')
```

this way I will get the value like `15:15:20`,but this `type` is varchar(or text).
How can I do to get the value in `time` type?

Thanks!

Comment: So, do you want to get time from '15:15:20'?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
SELECT  TO_TIMESTAMP('15:15:20', 'HH24:MI:SS')::TIME
```

Note that your very query (which returns local time) can be rewritten as

```
SELECT  LOCALTIME
```

which would return `TIME`